# Ordering by inches value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I've searched for the answer to this but can't quite work it out. I think I'm close but need your help please.

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT `size` 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY `size` 
ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTR(size, 1, POSITION('/' IN size) - 1), UNSIGNED INTEGER) ASC,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(size,'/',1)/SUBSTRING_INDEX(size,'/',-1) ASC
```

Running this gives the following result:

```
1"
2"
4"
3"
1/2"
3/8"
3/4"
11/4"
11/2"
21/2"
```

I need the sizes to come out smallest to largest. Any help on this would be massively appreciated. Thank you.

Note, I have also tried removing the " from the sizes in the database and the result was exactly the same.

An example of the dataset:

```
1 1/2"
1 1/4"
1"
1/2"
1/4"
1/8"
10"
11/2"
11/4"
11/4""
12"
14"
16"
2 1/2"
2"
21/2"
3"
3/4"
3/8"
4"
5"
6"
8"
```

Comment: The dataset is over 100 unique values, but every piece of data is either a fraction such as 1/2", or 21/2" or a whole and fraction such as 3 1/2". I hope that makes sense?

Comment: How's this for a sample? 1 1/2",1 1/4",1",1/2",1/4",1/8",10",11/2",11/4",11/4"",12",14",16",2 1/2",2",21/2",3",3/4",3/8",4",5",6",8"

Comment: That's nice. Maybe edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Lovely data format.  I think you are going to have to do the division.  The calculation is something like this:

```
order by (case when size like '%/%'
               then (substring_index(size, '/', 1) + 0) / (substring_index(size, '/', 2) + 0)
               else size + 0
          end)
```

Even if the `"` is part of the field, this will still work.  The `+ 0` does "silent" conversion.  That is, it converts the string up to the first non-numeric character.

EDIT:

If you could have spaces with whole numbers first, you would do:

```
order by (case when size like '% %/%'
               then (substring_index(size, 1, ' ') + 0) +
                    ((substring_index(substring_index(size, ' ', 2), '/', 1) + 0) /
                     (substring_index(size, '/', -1) + 0)
                    )
               when size like '%/%'
               then (substring_index(size, '/', 1) + 0) / (substring_index(size, '/', 2) + 0)
               else size + 0
          end)
```

Comment: You, sir, are absolutely out of this world awesome. Thank you so much! Brilliant!

Comment: One quick question... how could I amend your answer to deal with return values of 1 1/2",
1 1/4",
1",
1/2",
11/2",
11/4",
2 1/2",
2",
21/2",
3",
3/4",
3/8",
4",
5",
6",
8" ?

Comment: Thank you for your edit. It's VERY close but it will return a resultset such as: 1 1/4",
1 1/2",
2 1/2",
1/2",
3/4",
1",
2",
3",
4"

Answer (score 0):

You query almost work. However in first part of the order by you should substract the position from the string length.

```
SELECT `size`
FROM `size` 
GROUP BY `size` 
ORDER BY CONVERT(SUBSTR(size, 1, LENGTH(size) - POSITION('/' IN size) - 1), UNSIGNED INTEGER) ASC,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(size,'/',1)/SUBSTRING_INDEX(size,'/',-1) ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd0658/6